# What is initscopedepth in ActionScript bytecode AVM2? Why getlocal_0 and pushscope?

Tags: actionscript-3, bytecode, avm2

I have looked into the [AVM2 Overview document](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/avm2overview.pdf) (chapter 4.11, page 33) and found the following about `init_scope_depth`:

> `init_scope_depth`
> The init_scope_depth field defines the minimum scope depth, relative to `max_scope_depth`, that may be accessed within the method.
> `max_scope_depth`
> The max_scope_depth field defines the maximum scope depth that may be accessed within the method. The difference between `max_scope_depth` and `init_scope_depth` determines the size of the local scope stack.

I have also came across a citation on the [ActionScript 3.0 Bible book](https://books.google.pt/books?id=6uhORLiHHiwC&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false) about the scope chain, which I believe to be related to `init_scope_depth`, and says:

> The scope chain, shown in figure 2-1, is an internal device that is created to manage variable scope during function execution.
> When a variable is referenced, the Flash Player starts with the most recent function called and checks for variable declarations. If the value isn't found in the most local scope, it moves up one level to the parent function that called the function and checks there. This process continues until the scope chain has been checked all the way up to the global scope.

[Figure2-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY1TR.png)

As shown in the figure, we have the scope order being, from top to bottom:

`function scope -> parent function(s) scope (if any) -> instance of the class calling the function -> static instance of the class calling the function -> global scope`

Notice also that the scope chain can have more levels depending on class inheritance.

Now here comes my question:

I've been playing with JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler and RABCDAsm, and I have a class called `Global` in a package called `Data`. The class does not extend any other classes, but implements one interface. Within this class, there are normal methods and static methods. I have noticed that the static methods have `initscopedepth` set to 3 and the normal methods have `initscopedepth` set to 4. (Note: these values were set by the compiler, as explained in the [AVM2 Overview document](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/avm2overview.pdf), chapter 4.11).

My guess is that the initial scope is:

`method -> instance of class -> static instance of class (static variables) -> global`

But I am not sure and was wondering if anyone could confirm this.

This also leads me to another question. All the methods `code` block, both normal and static, start with the code:

```
getlocal_0
pushscope
```

(Note: After these 2 instructions comes whatever instruction the method starts with.)
Could it be because, for normal objects it is pushing the `this` onto the scope stack, and for static methods it is pushing the static instance of the class onto the scope stack? If so, why is this necessary?

Comment: **(1)** _"I have noticed that the static methods have `initscopedepth` set to 3 and the normal methods have `initscopedepth` set to 4."_ It's possible that JPEXS is doing that by itself as a feature of output. Perhaps needed to make the decompiled code work correctly. **(2)** Does your `getlocal_0` and `pushscope` get followed by a `pushnull` and `newfunction`? I think this is also a standard thing that JPEXS does when setting up a decompiled bytecode. Maybe someone else can explain the why... What problem is this causing that you need to solve?

Comment: @VC.One (1) It is not JPEXS' doing. These values are created by the compiler and are part of the method body's bytecode, as can be seen in the AVM2 Overview document (chapter 4.11). The same values appear in RABCDAsm. Also when creating a new method using JPEXS "Add trait" option, it gives a `initscopedepth` of 1 and `maxscopedepth` of 1, even though it adds the `getlocal_0` and `pushscope` automatically, so clearly not knowing what it's doing. (2) No. It is followed by whatever instruction the function starts with. (3) The problem is that I want to know how the scope chain is working here.

Comment: Okay I thought you had a runtime issue to solve. If you want theory of _"how the scope chain is working here"_ then also ask at [**as3lang.org**](https://discuss.as3lang.org/) since the admin there (@Zwetan) loves to discuss the workings of AVM2. You might get a faster answer there. Here it's at risk of not being useful to future readers (_eg: how does the final answer help to fix a not-working app for others?_)

Comment: @VC.One This question is useful in case I want to edit an SWF file to which I have not access to the source code. I have put forth this question in as3lang.org, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I believe that I've figured out the answer after some more research and thinking. The key to the puzzle was figuring out two more things.

1. All classes extend the `Object` class by default, as explained in [this book](https://books.google.pt/books?id=cJmsuCUGODQC&pg=SA2-PA109&lpg=SA2-PA109).
2. On method entry, the scope stack is empty and has room for `max_scope_stack` values, as explained in chapter 3.3.3 of AVM2 Overview.

Therefore, the initial scope depth is:
`global -> Object class -> MyClass class (static instance)`

And thus, the initial scope depth in this case is 3. I have noticed that functions outside classes have initial scope depth of 1 (the global scope only). And methods that are not static have initial scope depth of 4 (they also have MyClass object).

Because the scope stack is empty when we enter a method, and because register 0 holds the `this` object (which is the static instance, in the case of static methods, or the class itself if you prefer), we must push this object onto the scope stack so that we can access all the variables and methods on its scope chain. We have of course the scope of the method itself, which makes the max scope depth to be 4.